# Correct way to declare an NSArray (Memory-Wise)

Tags: memory-management, nsarray

I have an NSArray which has the properties nonatomic and retain. What I would like to know is am I initialising it in the correct way so that the retain count is what it should be?

The _lengthArr is the @synthesized ivar of lengthArr in my.h

```
@synthesize lengthArr = _lengthArr;

_lengthArr = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10 Minutes", @"20 Minutes", @"30 Minutes", @"1 Hour", @"2 Hours", @"5 Hours", @"5 Hours +", nil] retain];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning to an ivar there, so the code you posted will do what you want. You could also use `_lengthArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...]`, which would avoid a useless autorelease.

Or you could do `self.lengthArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]` to allow the setter to automatically retain it, although it is recommended to avoid this in initialization methods.

Comment: It is already assigned in the .h. I don't think I made it clear in the post. Please take another look.